# Possible to build an IPA file on Linux/Window?

Tags: windows, xcode, unix, ios

Is it possible to build an IPA file with XCode on a non-Mac OS like Windows or (preferably) Linux and preferably without the use of a VM? If yes, what is required to do so?

I did do a basic search and even posted a question on Apple support forum (forums.developer.apple.com/message/11494#11494). I did not find any recent information on this so hence my question hoping you guys would provide faster answer than Apple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Building an IPA requires Xcode which requires OS X.

Comment: Thanks, pretty much the answer I expected. Out workaround will probably be to run a Jenkins agent on the Mac which can then be triggered from the master Jenkins which is running on linux.